# About videos of the lectures by Enrico Bombieri

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta

Let me first apologize: this is not a technical question, it is a reference request .

Enrico Bombieri delivered series of lectures for
["GÖRAN GUSTAFSSON Lectures in Mathematics"](https://www.math.kth.se/GGlectures/bombieri.html)
and for
[ISSNAF](https://www.issnaf.org/web/index.php?view=article&catid=36:tricks-and-tracks&id=397:progetto-roccas-doctoral-and-postdoc-mit-apply-by-may-20&format=pdf&option=com_content&Itemid=71)
on the history and results on Riemann Zeta function.

I could find the links related to it; but, I couldn't find any video of lectures (there is a high chance that they were recorded).

So if anyone knows about them, please share.

Comment: What is it about exactly ?

Comment: @renus it's like survey lectures . You can see the links for details .

Comment: Usually if a lecture series is recorded, then the website of the lecture series will have it. So if you can't find it by a simple Google search, then it almost certainly doesn't exist.